# Android Application Runtime

Tags: android, runtime

I have found the following image over the net, while looking for Android Application Runtime. Can someone tell me whether the information given in this is correct or whether you would suggest any modifications.

Here is the image...

[image]

Comment: Do you have any problems in this image?

Comment: No, I don't exactly know the steps in the application runtime. So, just want to know whether the steps given in the image are correct.

Comment: Very much correct @VamsiChalla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this looks fairly correct!